# Is there any way to get information about user login?

Tags: myob

Is there a way to use the MYOB API to get the user login my.MYOB account information, get the login name and password in the picture below, can not write dead, if you can not get this information, then how to assign X-myobapi-CFTOKEN Give her, do you need to write death in the program?

[image]

Is there any way to get information about user login? 
Thanks!

Comment: "write death in the program" <-- what do you mean?

Comment: Means writing the kind of program that can't be changed.